# ¿Cómo agregar borde a celda con openxml en PowerPoint?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando cambiar el borde superior de una tabla en PowerPoint por medio de OpenXml, pero no me ha resultado. Actualmente la celda posee un borde a la izquierda, derecha y abajo, pero al intentar copiar el borde de abajo y agregarlo al borde superior, PowerPoint no refleja el cambio.

¿Qué me falta por modificar o que estoy haciendo mal para que funcione?

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código para copiar el borde y reemplazarlo.

```
   BottomBorderLineProperties btp = (BottomBorderLineProperties)celda.TableCellProperties.BottomBorderLineProperties.CloneNode(true);

   TopBorderLineProperties tbp = new TopBorderLineProperties()
   {
         Alignment = btp.Alignment,
         CapType = btp.CapType,
         CompoundLineType = btp.CompoundLineType,
         MCAttributes = btp.MCAttributes,
         Width = btp.Width
    };

   foreach(OpenXmlElement element in btp.ChildElements)
   {
       tbp.Append(element.CloneNode(true));
   }

   celda.TableCellProperties.TopBorderLineProperties = tbp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la version en ingles de StackOverflow obtuve mi respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548311/how-to-add-border-to-cell-with-openxml-in-powerpoint

En resumen:

Además, de agregar el borde superior de la celda que se quiere agregar. Se debe agregar el borde inferior en la celda ubicada directamente arriba.